# Completar próximo campo sem usuario ter que dar TAB

Tags: php, javascript

Ao clicar no botão ao lado de UF o usuário abre uma tabela com os estados do Brasil, e a partir da escolha do Estado os outros campos são completados, até ai tudo bem eu consegui fazer, porém tenho que clicar dentro do input e depois em outro lugar ou dar TAB, para completar os campos, tem alguma forma de eu adaptar minha função para que complete o campo imediatamente, sem precisar dar TAB ou qualquer coisa do tipo ? Para facilitar a vida do usuário

index.php

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='estado']").on("change", function(){
        var $nome_estado = $("input[name='nome_estado']");
        var $aliq_base_icms = $("input[name='aliq_base_icms']");
        var $aliq_icms = $("input[name='aliq_icms']");
        var $icms_subst_sn = $("input[name='icms_subst_sn']");
        var $insc_est_subst = $("input[name='insc_est_subst']");
        var $aliq_icms_subst = $("input[name='aliq_icms_subst']");
    
        $.getJSON('function_est.php',{
                estado: $ ( this ).val()
        },function( json ){
                $nome_estado.val ( json.nome_estado );
                $aliq_base_icms.val ( json.aliq_base_icms );
                $aliq_icms.val ( json.aliq_icms );
                $icms_subst_sn.val ( json.icms_subst_sn );
                $insc_est_subst.val ( json.insc_est_subst );
                $aliq_icms_subst.val ( json.aliq_icms_subst );
        });
    });   
});
</script>

<div class="col-lg-12">  
    <div class="col-lg-3 input-group" style="padding-left:16px;"><!-- Inicio Input ID -->
        <label for="ex1">UF: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control estado" name="estado">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top:25px;" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">...</button>
        </span><br>
    </div><br>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-5"><!-- Inicio Input ID -->
        <label for="ex1">Estado: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_estado"><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-lg-3"><!-- Inicio Input ID -->
        <label for="ex1">Alíquota Base do ICMS: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="aliq_base_icms"><br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">  
    <div class="col-lg-3"><!-- Inicio Input ID -->
        <label for="ex1">Alíquota do ICMS: </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="aliq_icms"><br>
    </div>
</div>

                <script>
                        $(document).on('click', '.get-estado', function() {
                            var value = $(this).text();
                            $('.close').trigger('click');
                            $('.estado').val(value);
                        });
                        $(document).on('click', '.get-nome_estado', function() {
                            var value = $(this).siblings('.get-estado').text();
                            $('.close').trigger('click');
                            $('.estado').val(value);
                        });
                </script>
```

function_est.php

```
<?php

include_once("conn.php");

function retorna($estado, $conn){

    $result = "SELECT * FROM estados WHERE estado = '$estado' ";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

    // DECLARA A VARIAVEL
    $valores = array();

    if($resultado){

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $valores['nome_estado'] = $row['nome_estado'];
        $valores['aliq_base_icms'] = $row['aliq_base_icms'];
        $valores['aliq_icms'] = $row['aliq_icms'];
        $valores['icms_subst_sn'] = $row['icms_subst_sn'];
        $valores['insc_est_subst'] = $row['insc_est_subst'];
        $valores['aliq_icms_subst'] = $row['aliq_icms_subst'];

    } else {
        return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
    }

        return json_encode($valores);

}

if(isset($_GET['estado'])){
        echo retorna($_GET['estado'], $conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual é o código que você usa para o modal inserir o valor selecionado no input?

Comment: vou colocar abaixo do código html, mas ele captura os dados vindos do modal normalmente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está utilizando a função através do *event handler* *onblur* (ou apenas *blur* no jquery). Ou seja, será executado sempre que o campo perder o estado de foco (*onfocus*).

Nesse caso, altere a sua função javascript para utilizar algua evento como o *onchange*:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
    <option value="">-- selecione --</option>
    <option value="Valor 1">Valor 1</option>
    <option value="Valor 2">Valor 2</option>
</select>
```

**Update**

Houve um detalhe que me passou despercebido. Esse detalhe é a forma que o seu código insere o valor selecionado no modal para o `input`. Infelizmente, o evento *onchange* somente é disparado (*triggered*) quando ocorre uma interação via usuário. O seu input está tendo uma interação via código. Através do seguinte trecho:

```
$('.estado').val(value);
```

Dessa forma, você tem duas opções, mover o código de update para dentro do código JavaScript ou realizar *trigger* do evento de forma manual. Eu acho a segunda opção mais simples.

Basta que, aonde você insere o valor, insira também a chamada do evento `change`:

```
$('.estado').val(value).change();
```

Comment: Não funcionou, do mesmo jeito tenho de dar TAB

Comment: @VictorT. dizer que não funcionou é muito abrangente. Por favor, atualize seu código com as novas implementações para podermos verificar o ocorrido.

Comment: Desculpe, não quis dizer isso e tirar seu mérito, porém eu coloco SP ou seleciono na tabela dentro do modal e mesmo assim para a função ser chamada tenho de ou dar tab ou clicar fora do campo input UF

Comment: @VictorT. sem problemas, apenas preciso saber como você implementou, pois, o código acima deveria funcionar sem problemas.

Comment: editei o script dentro do index

Comment: @VictorT. código atualizado, deve resolver seu problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara me ajudou bastante, se eu quiser também fazer um evento que a medida que o usuário digite diretamente no campo input sem clicar no modal e completar, também consigo ?

Comment: Sim, apenas pode ser possível que tenha que adequar qual o melhor evento a ser disparado. _onchange_ será disparado sempre que houver qualquer alteração (adicionou uma letra, é disparado).

Answer (score 2):

Adiciona um *listener* no `document` que irá verificar o valor no `input` `estado` quando houver cliques na página (quando você escolher uma opção na modal). Caso haja alterações no referido `input`, a função é chamada:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var estado_form = $('input[name=estado]'); // armazeno o elemento numa variável
    var estado_val = estado_form.val(); // pego o valor original
    $(document).on("click", function(){
        if(estado_val != estado_form.val() && estado_form.val() != ""){ // verifico se o valor é diferente e não pode estar vazio
            estado_val = estado_form.val(); // atribuo valor atual

            var $nome_estado = $("input[name='nome_estado']");
            var $aliq_base_icms = $("input[name='aliq_base_icms']");
            var $aliq_icms = $("input[name='aliq_icms']");
            var $icms_subst_sn = $("input[name='icms_subst_sn']");
            var $insc_est_subst = $("input[name='insc_est_subst']");
            var $aliq_icms_subst = $("input[name='aliq_icms_subst']");

            $.getJSON('function_est.php',{
                    estado: estado_form.val()
            },function( json ){
                $nome_estado.val ( json.nome_estado );
                $aliq_base_icms.val ( json.aliq_base_icms );
                $aliq_icms.val ( json.aliq_icms );
                $icms_subst_sn.val ( json.icms_subst_sn );
                $insc_est_subst.val ( json.insc_est_subst );
                $aliq_icms_subst.val ( json.aliq_icms_subst );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Não estava chamando a função, adicionei var na segunda e terceira linha e agora chama a função logo que recebe os dados no campo UF, porém retorna valores nulos

Comment: @VictorT. Blz, vou analisar aqui.

Comment: @VictorT. O problema está no `$( this ).val()`. Mude para `estado_form.val()`

Comment: Obrigado, agora deu o resultado esperado